# Kong OAUTH2 authenticated_userid validation against access token in Auth Code Flow

Tags: oauth-2.0, kong, api-gateway

I have successfully setup Kong v0.11.1 and secured APIs using oauth2 auth code flow.

oauth2 plugin was addedd on API level.
config.global_credentials = true

The issue is that if I generate a token for authenticated_userid = user1, I can use the access token to make a successful call to the upstream API and if authenticated_userid = user2 is making call with the same access token generated for user1 the request is successful as well.

Is there a setting in Kong that needs to be set so it can validate the authenticated_userid  with the access token on each call to the upstream API by the client app or do I have to implement this validation using the Upstream headers?

Comment: did you find solution for this ?

Comment: @kumar Yes, I had a workaround, so what I did was to extract the authenticated_user_id from the upstream header sent in by Kong in my backend service. I used the authenticated_userid to serve only resources belonging to the authenticated_user_id.  However, when using Kong oauth2 implicit flow I don't get receive that that particular header anymore, that's the X_authenticated_user_id. I hope this helps.